# Swift self referencing class property

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift

I am trying to create a self referencing class property in swift but I can't figure out why this isn't working.  I really just want to use this as a key for dispatch_set_specific to manage an private dispatch queue.

```
class SomeClass{
    var ptr:UnsafePointer<Void> = nil

    init() {
        withUnsafePointer(&ptr, {
            self.ptr  = $0
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe, you might want to use `unsafeAddressOf(self)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the closure `$0` is a pointer to `ptr` and therefore has the type
`UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<Void>>`. You need to convert it to the type of `ptr`:

```
withUnsafePointer(&ptr, {
    self.ptr  = UnsafePointer($0)
})
```

This can also be written as:

```
ptr = withUnsafePointer(&ptr) { UnsafePointer($0) }
```

---

Any `UnsafePointer<T>` can be converted from a different `UnsafePointer<U>`:

```
/// Convert from a UnsafePointer of a different type.
///
/// This is a fundamentally unsafe conversion.
init<U>(_ from: UnsafePointer<U>)
```

and the type is inferred automatically from the context, so it is sufficient to write

```
UnsafePointer($0)
```

instead of

```
UnsafePointer<Void>($0)
```

---

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
var ptr = UnsafeRawPointer(bitPattern: 1)!

ptr = withUnsafePointer(to: &ptr) { UnsafeRawPointer($0) }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it.

self.ptr  = UnsafePointer($0) <-*Access to instance properties or methods*

Swift permits and even encourages you to omit self keyword when it can be done. The challenge is to determine the scenarios when self is obligatory and when optional.
In Swift self is a special property of an instance that holds the instance itself. Most of the times self appears in an initializer or method of a class, structure or enumeration.